# Install Apache Cordova on Archlinux

Tags: node.js, cordova

I installed it with
yaourt nodejs-cordova

I have the following settings:

```
node -v
v5.0.0

npm -v
3.3.10

which node
/usr/bin/node

which npm
/usr/bin/npm
```

Now I tried this:

```
sudo npm install -g cordova
```

But as result I get this:

```
npm WARN engine xmlbuilder@2.2.1: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x || 0.10.x"} (current: {"node":"5.0.0","npm":"3.3.10"})
/usr/bin/cordova -> /usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova
/usr/lib
└── cordova@5.3.3
```

Is it a version problem?
Can anyone help me?

Because now, when trying to create a new project I get this:

```
Creating a new cordova project.
Could not find directory: /usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/cordova-app-hello-world
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution on this site: https://ervinloh.wordpress.com/2015/06/07/solving-npm-warn-engine-cordova-js3-8-0-wanted-warning/

It is possible to force npm to install the newest Cordova version with:

```
npm install -g cordova@4
```

Doing this, everything works fine.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to say with the output you've shown, but there is some dependency of `cordova` that is depending on an outdated version of `xmlbuilder`.

Newer versions of `xmlbuilder` use a different node version compatibility specifier:

```
"engines": {
  "node": ">=0.8.0"
},
```

This makes it compatible with newer versions of node.js (including v5.0.0).

**EDIT:**

[Here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7b42065ab7f854df7ea8) is the dependency tree for `cordova`. In there we see that the problematic dependency link goes like `cordova@5.3.3` ->  `cordova-lib@5.3.3` -> `plist@1.1.0` -> `xmlbuilder@2.2.1`. So then looking at each project in the chain, it's evident that several things need to happen:

- An issue needs to be created at the [`plist` issue tracker](https://github.com/TooTallNate/plist.js/issues) telling them to publish a new version because they already have their `package.json` pointing to the newer `xmlbuilder` with the fixed `engines` list.
- After that is done, an issue needs to be created on the [`cordova` issue tracker](http://wiki.apache.org/cordova/ReportingBugs) (requires a JIRA account there) telling them to update their dependency to use the newly published `plist`.

Comment: I don't really understand, what I have to do.